# How to select records whose column from one query is NOT between columns of other query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to take records from QUERY1 whose `time` is between `timeFrom` and `timeTo` from QUERY2

1. How I can combine those 2 queries? What is the most efficient way?
2. I think it will be more efficient to select records from `t1` whose `time` is between `timeFrom` and `timeTo` from QUERY2, and only after that join it with `t2`, right? 
   If yes, how do I do it with one query?

**NOTE**
: table `t1` has about 2 millions records!

**QUERY1**

```
SELECT ..., time
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.time >= t2.starttime
```

**QUERY2**

```
SELECT timeFrom, timeTto
FROM (...) t3 RIGHT JOIN 
     (...) t4 ON t3.rownum = t4.rownum
```

Comment: @AmitChotaliya, did you see my queries and my post or you just answered according to the subject without even reading what I've written?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a 3-way join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.time >= t2.starttime
JOIN (SELECT timeFrom, timeTo
      FROM (...) t3
      RIGHT JOIN (...) t4 ON t3.rownum = t4.rownum) t5
ON t1.time BETWEEN t5.timeFrom AND t5.timeTo
```

Let the query scheduler figure out the order to perform the joins. But if that doesn't work, you can try to assist it by reordering into a subquery:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT t1.*
      FROM t1
      JOIN (SELECT timeFrom, timeTo
            FROM (...) t3
            RIGHT JOIN (...) t4 ON t3.rownum = t4.rownum) t5
      ON t1.time BETWEEN t5.timeFrom AND t5.timeTo) t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.time >= t2.starttime
```

Also, make sure you have an index on `t1.time`.

For `NOT BETWEEN`, you need to use an outer join or a not exists query:

```
SELECT id, time
FROM myTable t
LEFT JOIN filterTable ft ON t.time BETWEEN ft.fromTime AND ft.toTime
WHERE ft.fromTime IS NULL

SELECT id, time
FROM myTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM filterTable
                  WHERE t.time BETWEEN fromTime AND toTime)
```

This is similar to the queries you have to use to find rows in a table that have no matching row in another table. The only difference is the condition is `BETWEEN` rather than `=`.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f595/16)